# urllib.urlopen does not work for this url though mechanize works

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize, urllib

My code below doesn't work for the URLs in nytimes which are articles. Please try changing the URL variable to something else and you'll see that it works. Why is that?

```
#url = "http://www.nytimes.com";
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/07/07/upshot/how-england-italy-and-germany-are-dominating-the-world-cup.html"
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url);
htmltext = htmlfile.read();
print htmltext;
```

Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think NYT validates your request with cookies. If the request isn't an ordinary request by web browser, the server returns Location header. It makes your request get lost.

The solution is simple. Use cookiejar like this:

```
import cookielib, urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/07/07/upshot/how-england-italy-and-germany-are-dominating-the-world-cup.html"
htmlfile = opener.open(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read();

print htmltext
```

Comment: Thanks a lot taggon. Of course, that worked :)
I spent a few hours reading up about openers and handlers and how cookies are handled.

But I have one more question - In general,how do you come to know that adding cookies would solve the problem? I mean, the earlier response doesn't give any leads, it just gives an empty result.

Comment: @user3237941 Cookie is most common method to block non-human requests.   When I access the page at first time it redirects me twice, but never redirects me since then. It means NYT uses some method to find my first visit. Mostly it is cookie because server-side application can know it. So, I have improved your code to preserve cookies and done. :)

Comment: Thanks taggon. 

Just one more question. How do I see that the page is redirected twice? Is it if I see the GET request for the page twice in the Network tab in "Inspect element"?

When you say that the page redirects twice, I'm assuming the following : The First request is when nytimes is loaded. But it cannot load the page because the page at nytimes requires a cookie. So,it tells the browser that it needs to make a cookie before it can access nytimes and sends it back. The second request is when the browser reloads/tries nytimes once again but this time with the cookie it has constructed.

Comment: @user3237941 Exactly. That is what I meant by "redirects twice". I used [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) on my Windows machine to watch the requests and create a dummy one, but Chrome DevTools Network tab would be a good option also if you turn on Preserve log.

Answer (score 0):

By "doesn't work" I presume you mean it doesn't give you the expected content. I get an empty result when I access that URL using `urllib` so this is likely yet another aspect of the NYT's "paywall."

Comment: Thanks for the reply holdenweb. Yes I get an empty result.
Does this happen quite often with a lot of URLs?